# Building Alexa Skill that pushes an alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build an alexa skill that fires a custom alarm every set number of times per day (30 min intervals for example). I'm reading through their docs and not fulling understanding where to go to next.

Does anyone have some good Alexa skill apps that I can reference or an article? I couldn't find much online and it looks like it hasn't been an accessible feature for too long.

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer since we don't exactly know where you are stuck and we got not example codes. We are here to help you with issues about your code or understanding a development language, maybe with some tips or tricks. But this is pretty broad, opinion based and doesn't seem like you have tried or started anything. Maybe take a look at this small article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry there isn't much real code here. I was looking for more of a project or youtube to help understand. It seems like it's a tougher problem than I thought starting out.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot trigger Alexa to speak without user interaction. That means, the user has to say something to trigger your skill, which will in turn create a request to you skill's backend, and you can only respond (be it audio or speech) back to that request.

However, you can send Push Notifications.

> Notification indicators inform end users that new content is available
>   from Alexa skills and domains. When a notification is delivered,
>   depending on what the product is capable of, the user is notified by
>   visual and audio indicators.

More on Push Notification [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html)

Comment: I thought you could send reminders. Such as here:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/enable-named-timers-and-reminders.html

Comment: no, that's AVS, it's not the same as ASK. Cicil is right

Comment: @Cicil Thomas 
Is there a way to communicate a message  from Alexa 1 (front door) to Alexa 2 (warehouse)
 ??

Comment: @mohitsharma You cannot trigger a device without a user interaction. However, there is a `deviceId` property in each request that you can use to distinguish between the various devices from which a user interacts.